# What was Max Brod saying about Kafka?

Tags: listening-comprehension

In the following interview, Max Brod talks about Kafka, but there's a bit that I can't quite figure out.  Starting at 19'20, he says:

- Es finden sich unter seinen Tagebuchaufzeichnungen Berichte, die…, Berichte aus dem Krieg, [???], und vor dem Krieg geschrieben sind.  Und einmal schildert er sogar…

https://youtu.be/HLLoWh45jOA?t=1157

The bit I don't get is between "aus dem Krieg" and "und vor dem Krieg".  The automatic subtitles suggest "Kriegen", but I don't hear the /g/ of /kri:gən/ at all, although it might have something to do with Brod's accent.

Comment: He clarifies: "Das klingt wie eine seherische Vision dessen was dann später geschehen ist" - like a prophetic vision of what happened later. That was super interesting thanks for the link :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ich denke, Max Brod sagt Folgendes über den "prophetischen Zug", über das "Seherische" in Kafkas Werk:

> Es finden sich unter seinen Tagebuchaufzeichnungen Berichte, die ***wie***
> Berichte aus dem Krieg ***klingen***, und vor dem Krieg geschrieben sind.
> Und einmal schildert er sogar…

Das Verb "klingen" und das Adverb "wie" sind tatsächlich nur schwer zu verstehen.

Comment: Vielen Dank, ich hatte den genauen Aufbau des Satzes nicht recht verstanden, jetzt ist es mir klar geworden.